# GPG not working with python 3.8 but ok with 3.6

Tags: gnupg, python-3.8

I have just started dabbling with Python and I’m stuck with my first project
I need help in trying to make some sense out gpg. I have been struggle with trying to get gpg to work with python 3.8.1. If run the code in Thonny Python 3.6.9 in run just fine.

The version is gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4 libgcrypt 1.8.1
Home directory : /home/bob/.gnupg
gnupg : /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gnupg

using Python 3.6.9  works just fine

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pathlib import Path
import gnupg

# My gpg keys home directory.
#gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='/home/bob/.gnupg')
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/bob/.gnupg')

local_path = Path("/home/bob")
src_dir = ("/home/bob/Tbox/Channels2.csv")

with open(src_dir, 'rb') as afile:
   # text = afile.read()
    status = gpg.encrypt_file(afile,
        ['bobh@gunas.co.uk'],
        output='/home/bob/Tbox/Channels2.csv.gpg')

print('ok: ', status.ok)
print('status: ', status.status)
print('stderr: ', status.stderr)

SHELL OUTPUT
ok:  True
status:  encryption ok
stderr:  [GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 4678A2C439E752DA3DAE2EBA7357BB95381CD73 0
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 4678A2C439E752DA3DAE2EBA7357BB95381CD73 0
[GNUPG:] ENCRYPTION_COMPLIANCE_MODE 23
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_ENCRYPTION 2 9
[GNUPG:] END_ENCRYPTION
```

however if I run the code in Thonny Python 3.8.1 I not working withy error message in Shell

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pathlib import Path
import gnupg

# My gpg keys home directory.
gpg = gnupg.GPG(homedir='/home/bob/.gnupg')
#gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/bob/.gnupg')

local_path = Path("/home/bob")
backup_dir = Path("/home/bob/Tbox/tbackup-test")
src_dir = ("/home/bob/Tbox/Channels2.csv")

with open(src_dir, 'rb') as afile:
     text = afile.read()
   # status = gpg.encrypt_file(text,
    status = gpg.encrypt(afile,
        ['bobh@gunas.co.uk'],
        output='/home/bob/Tbox/Channels2.csv.gpg')

print('ok: ', status.ok)
print('status: ', status.status)
print('stderr: ', status.stderr)

SHELL OUTPUT
ok:  False
status:  None
stderr:  gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
```

I have tried add the line no-tty to the gpg.conf file but this did not help.

I have tried with some example of the net but with on joy, one problem I have found is to do with gpg and the word Context like c = gpg.core.Context(armor=True) error AttributeError: 'GPG' object has no attribute 'core'.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm also using python 3.8 and having issues

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, instead of:

```
status = gpg.encrypt(afile,
```

you probably need:

```
status = gpg.encrypt(text,
```

Basically you need to decide if you are encrypting a file, or **the contents of a file** (that you're reading in variable '`text`'), and then you either use `gpg.encrypt` or `gpg.encrypt_file` accordingly.

Comment: That is not the problem, as with python 3.6.9 I can encrypt a tar, 7zip, csv and txt or any file I llke. The problem is just with trying to use the code with python 3.8.1. I cannot find any info on the net as to what the problem maybe.